# Get Mono or Flux object type during runtime

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have Flux or Mono which is being populated with different custom objects which i am not aware of.

I want to retrieve Object class name without blocking the Flux or Mono.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by mapping `Mono` like such:

```
Mono<String> mono = Mono.just(...some object goes here)
    .map(object -> object.getClass().getSimpleName());
```

It should be relatively obvious what is going on here -- we are mapping the object to the object's class name (all while staying inside `mono`)

```
Flux<String> mono = Flux.fromIterable(...some list of objects)
    .flatMap(object -> object.getClass().getSimpleName);
```

(Note: I'm not super sure about `Flux`... writing this code without an IDE.  But it should be very close.)

Comment: Your code will result in compilation error as getSimpleName() wont give you a publisher in any case

Comment: How can i retrieve only String(className) without Mono? I don't want to use block on Mono<String> object.